# «Твой номер — шестнадцатый, помалкивай в трубочку, ясно?» — значение

Tags: значение-слов, смысл, словосочетания

Во время просмотра фильма "Место встречи изменить нельзя" наткнулся на следующее предложение:

> Твой номер — шестнадцатый, помалкивай в трубочку, ясно?

Что в данном случае означает *шестнадцатый номер* и почему именно шестнадцатый?
В выражении *помалкивай в трубочку* имеется в виду телефонная трубка?

Comment: Вариант непечатного слова из 3 букв, связанный с 16 напечатанными римскими цифрами XVI. Завуалированная брань из тюремного жаргона, означающая низкий статус собеседника в тюремной иерархии..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Среднее число запасных в самом популярном виде спорта тогда составляло около пяти игроков, и сквозной порядок номеров заявленного состава — не то, что современная «нумерация» по прихоти многочисленных звёзд — соответствовал общему числу спортсменов (около пятнадцати). Наставления Жеглова могли содержать отсылку к номеру на спине до поры не влияющего на игру запасного игрока. Возможно и не имеющего шанс быть не только в основе, но и на скамейке запасных.

С пустым местом не ведут разговоры, поэтому переговорная труба (на судне) и телефонная трубка превратились в унизительную трубочку.

Comment: Номера на футболках стали обязательными с 1939 года. Общая численность сборной СССР на первых её турнирах — 20 игроков. Замены проводились уже в отборочном турнире к чемпионату мира 1954 года, а в 1958 году были разрешены законодательно (при трамве вратаря и одного полевого). Но на клубном уровне замены (в том числе тактические) проводились с довоенного времени: профессионального статуса команда любого класса у нас в стране не имела.

Подробнее на «Чемпионате»:
https://www.championat.com/football/article-3170879-kak-menjalis-futbolnye-pravila.html?utm_source=copypaste

Answer (score 1):

> В выражении помалкивай в трубочку имеется в виду телефонная трубка?

Скорее уж - ***переговорная труба на судне***, по которой капитан ("первый номер") или лицо, его подменяющее, дает команды рулевому и/или в машинное отделение.

Тут, правда, есть одна (кажущаяся) нестыковочка: рулевой и машинист вовсе не молчали в трубу, а непременно докладывали о принятии приказа и его исполнении.
Но тут важно то, что по своей инициативе младшие "номера" в "трубку" никогда не говорили - разве что в случае доклада о чрезвычайной ситуации, требующей принятия экстренных мер.
Так что тут есть прямое соответствие с выражением Жеглова.

"Футбольные" версии несостоятельны изначально. Ни о каких 15 игроках в заявке речь не идет. В футболе замены появились не ранее середины 50-х годов, то есть в заявке в те времена всегда было ровно 11 фамилий.

(+)==========
добавлено после комментария автора вопроса.
Приведенная версия по части доказательности ничем не лучше многих других.
В чем её преимущество - так это в том, что она непротиворечиво объединяет две части высказывания Жеглова. И и то, что автор сам вспомнил о подобной (телефонная трубка). Сам же конкретный номер большого значения не имеет, он, можно сказать, "...надцатый".

Что до других версий, то они в большинстве своем дают объяснения по частям: трубочка, например, ошибочно интерпретация "тряпочки" ("помалкивай в тряпочку" встречалось и до Жеглова), а про номер - вообще куча объяснений. Хотя более или менее разумными выглядят всего несколько, одна - связана и бильярдом, 16-й номер (в некоторых играх) - биток, очкового значения не имеет. Да вот беда - номера на битке обычно нету.

Comment: _"Футбольные" версии несостоятельны изначально._ - В Вашем ответе нет объяснения того, почему использован именно шестнадцатый номер и что он означает.

Comment: JConstantine  *почему использован именно шестнадцатый номер* - а у меня нету объяснения. Думаю, его нет вообще, как вы верно заметили, можно было хоть 25-м назвать. По моим представлениям важен не конкретный номер, а то, что он далеко не первый.

Answer (score 0):

А возможно некий цифровой показатель степени невежества, малоинформированности.Часто встречается на Украине (даже в книгах на местных диалектах и не только ) выражение идиома "туман шестнадцатый", употребляемое именно, чаще всего в невежливой форме, как несущее смысл: "ты туп" или "тебе это известно только в общих чертах"равно как и "ты далек от понимания " или" ты этого не знаеш" и т.д. Возможны разные ситуации и колчство участников (ты,он,она,мы,они, и т.д.), но само слово "туман" в этой (я здесь имею ввиду только укр-яз)фразе объязательно. Бегемот дотошный ботан и только. Кстати действительно всегда создается вчепетление что "туман 10й" будет более грамотен чем 16-й Вероятно Жеглов использует идиому славянизм. "Ты (Шарапов)пока еще не разбираешся,как следует в этих вопросах". Близко к этому будет фраза "ты пока еще тут без году неделя, как работаеш". Да и в следственном отделе есть еще персонаж Тараскин (малороссиянин) и по-сценарию иногда звучат Украинские фразы. Опять же известное выражение "молчи в тряпочку" вероятно (окультуренное)ругательство, нечто вроде желания заткнуть тряпкой чтоб по-молчал.Ну и телефонная связь на то время была почитаема более роскошью чем "средством", как в наше время...даже на фото позировали с "трубочкой"А о "трубочке" лучше здесь не углублятся! Фильм ведь о криминальном мире и :) сопутствующих ему явлениях.